# Matching number of rows in one excel table with the number of rows in another

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel I am using some columns for calculations that will use information from some other columns who's information is copied from another file. This external data can have a varying number of rows, however, so I am trying to figure out some vba code that will pull down the calculations or pull them up to expand or compress the rows to match the imported data.

So for example, A is a column that is brought in from elsewhere and B is the calculation column.

```
A   B
1   A2*2
2   A3*2
3   A4*2
4   A5*2
```

Now suppose I copy in a column that has eight rows. I want to pull down column B so that it has eight rows as well. Any form guidance wouuld be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use a formula like `VLOOKUP()` to bring in the information from the other sheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams From what I gathered the OP is pulling it from a text file of some sort so the data is not contained on another sheet.  I am a huge fan of `VLOOKUP()` though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you can possibly do this manually with autofill, but if you wish to use a macro something like this could get you started:

```
Sub Macro1()

    ' put your function here
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*2"

    Dim dest As Integer
    dest = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    Range("B1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & dest), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

This will autofill a function in column B to as much data is contained in column A.  Now you stated that you need to *"expand or compress the rows to match the imported data."* You can do this by clearing the B column at the beginning of the macro.

Hopefully this helps, if this is confusing or does not help your problem let me know.